# .NET class as callback object in COM DLL

Tags: vb.net, com

I am a relative newcomer to Windows programming and VB.net.   What we are trying to do is call a function in an existing, 3rd party COM dll.  This function requires a callback parameter, whose type is an interface also defined in the dll.

In our VB.net application, we have added the dll as a COM reference, and created a class that implements the interface in the DLL.  We then send an object of that type as the callback parameter.  This compiles fine.  However, when we run the application, we receive an error stating that the program is unable to cast the object from our existing type to the interface type.

I suspect that there is a simple fix, but so far, my efforts to find a solution have come up short.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks very much.

Comment: could you post some code?  Maybe this issue : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FusionLoaderContextsUnableToCastObjectOfTypeWhateverToTypeWhatever.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check whether the COM interface which you are implementing has a registerd proxy/stub or a correspondent typelibrary (tlb). You may check this by searching the interface's IID (this is a guid assossiated with this interface) in the registry:

Proxy/stub case:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   Interface
      {iid}
         (Default) = ICustomInterfaceName
         ProxyStubClsid32 = {clsid}
```

Typelibrary case:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F37C8060-4AD5-101B-B826-00DD01103DE1}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F37C8060-4AD5-101B-B826-00DD01103DE1}\2.0 = Automation Hello 2.0 Type Library.
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F37C8060-4AD5-101B-B826-00DD01103DE1}\2.0\HELPDIR =
; U.S. English.
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F37C8060-4AD5-101B-B826-00DD01103DE1}\2.0\9\win32 = hello.tlb
```

Replace {F37C8060-4AD5-101B-B826-00DD01103DE1} with a guid assossiated with your typelibrary.

In case if the typelibrary is registered. Check if its file is present on your PC